# Strange behavior from ko.editables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using the [ko.editables](https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables) plugin for knockout, and it doesn't appear to be caching the previous value correctly. Does anyone have experience with this plugin?

If I do something like this:

```
var item = { Name: ko.observable("initial") };
selectedItem = ko.observable(item);
ko.editable(selectedItem);
selectedItem.beginEdit();
selectedItem().Name("second");
selectedItem.rollback();
```

What ends up happening is that selectedItem().Name is still "second", even though it should be "initial".

I looked into the source file, but I don't understand enough about the way JavaScript handles variables to know if what I'm seeing is right or wrong.

I set a breakpoint in the following place within ko.editables.js:

```
result.rollback = function () {
    if (inTransaction()) {
        result(oldValue); //breakpoint
        inTransaction(false);
    }
};
```

What I found was that oldValue had picked up the new value of the observable, even though commit was never called. Everything I've tried looks exactly like the samples. What am I missing?

**Update:**

I've updated the code sample. My original code *does* have the ko.editable() line in it, but thank you to Robert.westerland for pointing it out. It still doesn't work with this extra line.

Comment: Not familiar with this plugin, just wanted to note for consideration, a similar Modify/Revert behavior is  discussed in [A Simple Editor Pattern for Knockout.js](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html)

Comment: I don't know much about the ko.editable plugin, since I've never used it before, but if you look at the sample in the documentation (the readme-file displayed on the repo landing page) on the ko.editable page it seems as though your code should be `var item = { Name: ko.observable("initial") };
ko.editable(item);
item.beginEdit();
item.Name("second");
item.rollback();
console.log(item.Name());`. Using the code written here worked for me, in a very quick test.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but could be useful for others. I think you might need to call "commit" before the "beginEdit", and I also had to include "true" as a second parameter when calling ko.editable.

Your updated code::

```
var item = { Name: ko.observable("initial") };
selectedItem = ko.observable(item);
ko.editable(selectedItem, true);
selectedItem.commit();
selectedItem.beginEdit();
selectedItem().Name("second");
selectedItem.rollback();
```